# how to do a fade in/out while moving down css animation

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, fading

How can I make a button fade in/out on a loop while moving down with css animations? so far I got the fade in/out working fine. But I cant get them both to work at the same time.

```
<div class="down-arrow"><button class="down-button animate-flicker" type="button">VVV</button></div>

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
    from {top:0px; opacity: 0; } 
    to {top:200px;}
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation  {
    from {top:0px; opacity: 0; } 
    to {top:200px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation  {
    from {top:0px; opacity: 0; } 
    to {top:200px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation {
    from {top:0px; opacity: 0; } 
    to {top:200px;}
}
.animate-flicker {
    animation: flickerAnimation 1s infinite alternate;
   -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 1s infinite alternate;
   -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 1s infinite alternate;
   -o-animation: flickerAnimation 1s infinite alternate;   
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ywn9w5L9/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jairajdesai/ywn9w5L9/29/).

You just need to add a `position` attribute to your `animate-flicker` class in your existing `css`.

Check my code snippet below :

```js
@
keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0 % {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100 % {
    top: 200px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@ - o - keyframes flickerAnimation {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 200px;
  }
}

@ - moz - keyframes flickerAnimation {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 200px;
  }
}

@ - webkit - keyframes flickerAnimation {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 200px;
  }
}

.animate - flicker {
  position: absolute;
  animation: flickerAnimation 1s infinite alternate; - webkit - animation: flickerAnimation 1s infinite alternate; - moz - animation: flickerAnimation 1s infinite alternate; - o - animation: flickerAnimation 1s infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<div class="down-arrow">
  <button class="down-button animate-flicker" type="button">VVV</button>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but on your jfiddle the button doesnt move down? i just realized i didnt have a position set too and i figured that had to be it. but nothing changed with your code.

Comment: @Nick : Which browser are you using ? the fiddle works fine for me in chrome. if you are testing it in other browsers, you might need to change the css accordingly, I've only changed your css so as to test it on chrome.

Comment: ahh yeah it does work in chrome. i was on firefox and it doesnt work. how can i make it cross browser compatible? it doesnt seem to work with what i have here: https://jsfiddle.net/ywn9w5L9/24/

Comment: @Nick : Check my latest updated fiddle, the code is cross-broswer compatible, just add the `position` attribute to your `animate-flicker` class, and it should work fine on all browsers.(I've tested it myself and it works fine on chrome,IE and FF)

Comment: @Nick : Is my fiddle now working for you as intended on different browsers ?

Comment: got it thanks so much! i knew i was close. kinda rusty with my css and haven't used animations really before. works perfect